# How to get a Telerik Multi column combo box value which is a column in rad grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I want to get the first element of *telerik multi combo box* which is a column of a telerik grid view

when user selects a row i want to get the first element of that row and pass it to my DB

i've done some thing but i geuss it's not enough

```
    if (Ref_MultiColumnComboBox.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            var tr = Ref_MultiColumnComboBox.MultiColumnComboBoxElement
                .EditorControl.Rows[Ref_MultiColumnComboBox.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.SelectedIndex]
                    .Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("m= {0}" + "  //    " + tr);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("", "Error");
        }
```

the problem is that when user selects some row or doesn't `selectedindex` is allways `-1`

Comment: The reason it always -1 it because you're instantiating it. Remove this line       Ref_MultiColumnComboBox = new RadMultiColumnComboBox();

Comment: @Bayeni I correct what you mentioned but after this if i put a meesage  that message pops up

Comment: I don't get you, do you mean its working after removing that line?

Comment: @Bayeni no it's not,i thought it's working but it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it for **RadMultiColumnComboBox** control:

```
void radMultiColumnComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewDataRowInfo selectedRow = (GridViewDataRowInfo)radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedItem;
    Console.WriteLine(selectedRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
}
```

The SelectedItem provides a reference to the selected row in the inner grid, from where you can access its cells and values.

If **GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn** is used, then you can use either the ValueChanged event, or the CellValueChangned events to get the row of the currently selected item:

```
void radGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement mccbEditor = (RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement)e.ActiveEditor;
    GridViewDataRowInfo selectedRow = (GridViewDataRowInfo)mccbEditor.SelectedItem;
    Console.WriteLine(selectedRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
}

void radGridView1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement mccbEditor = (RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement)radGridView1.ActiveEditor;
    GridViewDataRowInfo selectedRow = (GridViewDataRowInfo)mccbEditor.SelectedItem;
    Console.WriteLine(selectedRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks,it's best answer so far,but problem here is that i'm using it inside of a telerik grid view and i coudn't find this      `radMultiColumnComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: and the name of that column is not radmulti..... and in my intelicens won't give me any thing,what should i do?

Comment: thank you so much,and how can i insert this values into a list??

Comment: If it is a string, create a List<string> and insert it there. Here is documentation on the matter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx